# Set cursor position in edittext android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have implemented a text editor type application in android, the issue is when i re-open the activity in which i have placed my multi-line edit text, the cursor is always set to the start position of the edit text. so when ever i tried to enter the text it was added to the start position, i solved this issue, by using,

```
EditText.setSelection(EditText.getText().length());
```

But now, i cannot edit any text that is already written in the edit text view because, my cursor always moves to the end of the text.

I want to place the cursor such that i can edit any text , any line any paragraph written in my edit text box, what should i do.

Below is the xml of my Edit text

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
```

Comment: Where did you added that code? If in watcher/ listener remove that. Put this code only at onCReate/ onResume.

Comment: I have used the code in a text watcher. i have to use text watcher as there are many functions that could not be performed well without it.

Comment: there is no any option then...

Comment: you mean i cannot implement this functionality using android? :/

Comment: No. I mean is if you put this code into watcher, you can not move selection on any place other than last.

Comment: so i should put the setSelection code outside the watcher right?

Comment: if i remove it from the textwatcher and place it in oncreate then the previous problem arises that the cursor remain at the start of the edittext

Comment: Can you explain your need.. when do you want to set selection?

Comment: i just dont want to use it, i need to place my cursor any where in the edit text view where i want to add some text

Comment: Then what is the problem? This is default behavior. Why did you add code into watcher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure you have resolved the problem after 3 months but I want to answer for someone who faces the same problem.
The problem is with this attribute: `android:gravity="top"`
When you use it, it doesn't let the cursor to move. I don't know why but after I deleted this line, it worked.

Comment: nice one bro. and yes i have solved it now. but +1 for your answer :)

Comment: @Hassaan Rabbani could you share how you solved this? I'm looking to do this with an EditText so a user can position the cursor to edit an entry. I'm not using the "android:gravity="top" " attribute.